# .attr() function isn't working

Tags: php, jquery

I know that this question has been asked and answered multiple times but the solutions i found isn't working for me.

this is the html element generated by php code :

```
<?php 

//here $index is a php variable and countIndex is my custom attribute

echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btnAction btnRemove tooltips" title="Remove" style="float:right" onclick="deleteData()" data-countIndex="'.$count.'"></span>';

?>
```

now when i click the span tag i want to alert it's custom attribute. And this is the code i used:

```
 function deleteData()
{
  alert( $( this ).data('countIndex') );

     // also tried these but didn't work
    // alert( jQuery( this ).attr( 'countIndex' ) );
   // alert( $( this ).attr( "class" ) );
}
```

I have verified it many times but i am not able to trace out the bug . Please find out the problem with my code.

Comment: Try: `alert($(e.target).attr('data-countIndex'));` I used this in a similar function but using a hover instead of a click.

Comment: Same problem again... returns 'undefined'

Comment: Note: If you are going to use jQuery, avoid using inline event handlers. Do it using jQuery event hookup. This will keep the handler with the registration and make for simpler code. It will also avoid problems like this.

Comment: @BibhutiAlmighty I have added a code snippet. You will get the answer on console. Please verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added hard coded the value **"11"** for `data-countIndex` to show a demo

```js
function deleteData(elem){
  console.log($(elem).attr("data-countIndex"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="deleteData(this)" data-countIndex="11">  
  test
</span>
```

**Please try this**

add "this"

**onclick="deleteData(this)"**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btnAction btnRemove tooltips" title="Remove" style="float:right" onclick="deleteData(this)" data-countIndex="'.$count.'"></span>

function deleteData(elem){
    alert($(elem).attr("data-countIndex"))
}
```

Comment: `elem.data - countIndex`? I don't think so.

Comment: @mooiamaduck I have added a code snippet. Please verify.

Comment: thanks man your solution worked. But can u please explain why yours worked and not mine. What's wrong with the  code i used ?

Comment: @BibhutiAlmighty: Passing this as a parameter is *not* the preferred solution for jQuery (only for raw JavaScript where you have less choices available).

Comment: The key is that, in this case, `.attr('data-countIndex')` works but `data('countIndex')` does not. See my post.

Comment: @BibhutiAlmighty you will cannot get "this" unless you pass as an argument when you are using a function

Comment: The caller can specify a value for `this` by using `func.call(value, arg1, ...)` or `func.apply(value, args)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `$(this).attr('data-countIndex')`. You access it by its full name just like any other attribute.

I believe that the reason `$(this).data('countIndex')` returns `undefined` is because `data` [automatically un-camel-cases its argument](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5). So it's actually looking for `data-count-index` instead of `data-countIndex`. If you had named your attribute `data-count-index` it would have worked.

Comment: Change `onclick="deleteData()"` to `onclick="deleteData"`. I didn't notice before but you're losing the context of the event handler by explicitly calling `deleteData`.

Comment: this is completely wrong and misleading advice. data() *will* return a matching data- attribute if there is no matching value stored against the element already. The problem lays elsewhere.

Comment: Totally my bad; it's late. Change it to `onclick="deleteData.call(this);`